# right line in callstack for Unity3D selfmade logger

Tags: logging, unity-game-engine, callstack

to achieve plattform indypendent logging, I build a logger class in my Unity Project. 
I create instances of my Logger and call it with functions like:

```
public virtual void LogError (string msg, Object o = null)
{
    if (Level >= LogLevel.Error)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(Formatter.Format(msg), o);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine. (I don't won`t discuss the way how this logging works.)

My Problem is, if i click on the error in unity editor, it jump to the line with the "Debug.LogError" code. But i whould prefer the line were i make the call to my Logger class.

```
myLogger.LogError("Something is broken");
```

Is this somehow possible?